# CryptoPro ошибка spki.algorithm.parameters

Tags: c#, криптопро

При переходе на новый алгоритм шифрования `ГОСТ Р 34.10-2012 256` сервер начал выдавать ошибку `spki.algorithm.parameters`, при этом на локальной машине все работает. Ошибка возникает при обращении к методу
`public static SymmetricAlgorithm DecryptKeyClass([] keyData, gost, symmetricAlgorithmUri)`. Внутри метода вызывается цепочка других методов в одном из которых вызывается метод `DecodeGostKeyTransport` где происходит следующее:

```
GostR3410_KeyTransport r3410KeyTransport = new GostR3410_KeyTransport();
r3410KeyTransport.Decode(buffer);
...
transport.transportParameters_ = cpAsnUtils.UnpackPublicKeyInfo2012(r3410KeyTransport.transportParameters.ephemeralPublicKey);
```

Поле `ephemeralPublicKey` является классом `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` и внутри метода `UnpackPublicKeyInfo2012` идет обращение к свойству данного класса и попытке каста к определенному типу:

```
Asn1Choice parameters = spki.algorithm.parameters as Asn1Choice;
if (parameters == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("spki.algorithm.parameters");
```

Почему на локальной машине все работает, следовательно параметры не null, а на сервере вылетает данный эксепшн с чем это может быть связано? Проверил криптопро контейнеры, переустанавливал сертификаты - ничего не поменялось.

Comment: а в чем вопрос собственно?

Comment: просто stackoverflow очень популярный ресурс куда многие обращаются в первую очередь для решения своей проблемы и я подумал, что я могу поделиться решением своей проблемы здесь. Возможно мне стоило задать вопрос и самому на него ответить? Как лучше оформить?)

Comment: вот набор ссылок по этому поводу: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7448/178576

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема была в версиях `CryptoPro .NET SDK` и `CryptoPro .NET Server`, после обновления с версии `1.0.6397` до `1.0.6893` все работает.